# i am getting "Missing artifact groupId:artifactId:version:lifecycle " while compiling the project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, artifacts

I am having problems compiling my company project made in maven and I am getting `Missing artifact groupId:artifactId:version:lifecycle`, so I have resolved most of the build path dependencies for jars, but now I am stuck with this one jar which is not present in the .m2 repository, so my doubt is if the jar is configured as dependency in pom.xml and it's not there in local repository (.m2/repository).

Can't maven just get it from central maven repository by just clicking pom.xml->run as -> maven build, or I have to put this file manually in the local repository?

Comment: If it is available in `central`, it should it is configured correctly. What is the artifact and can you post relevant error snippet?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that, if a dependency is not present in the local repository, it will be downloaded from the maven central repository. But if there's a project specific dependency which is not present in the central repository, you have to explicitly specify the repository in which the dependency is present.

You can search the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7C) to see if the artifact you want is present in here.

If it is not present, you can add the repository, containing the artifact you want, using `<repositories>` tag.

```
<repositories>  
    <respository> 
       <id>myRepository</id>   
       <url>my.repo.link</url>
    <repository>
</repositories>
```